# Exclude dependencies from a local Grails plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

I'm not seeing anything resembling an answer to this on the googlytubes so here goes...

We make use of several local plugins in our grails project. One of our plugins recently has a dependency on SLF4J. Our main webapp (that uses the plugin) also has a dependency on SLF4J. This results in the entirely harmless but nevertheless irritating warning at runtime:

```
Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

Typically I'd just define an "excludes" on the plugins SLF4J dependency, but since this is a local plugin I don't see any way to do so. I tried...

```
grails.plugin.location.'localpluginname' = '../localplugindir'

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    plugins {
        runtime("com.ourcompany:localpluginname:1.0") {
            excludes('slf4j-api')
        }
    }
}
```

...but then it tries to actually resolve said plugin on the remote repositories, and fails. We also don't want to exclude the dependency directly in the plugin because the plugin may be used in other projects which do not provide the dependency already.

Before anyone suggests we deploy our local plugin to a local maven repo in order to do this, let me get it out of the way that we don't want to do that. We have them local for a reason...so we can rapidly make changes and see said changes. We'd rather live with the annoying warning messages than add in the increased pain of deploying on every change.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are getting is not related to having multiple versions of the slf4j-api present in the classpath. SLF4J API is designed to bind with one and only one underlying logging framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the class path, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those bindings. You can read more about it in the [SLF4J warning or error messages and their meanings](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html) document.
The solution proposed by Slf4J is: When multiple bindings are available on the class path, select one and only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings.
In your case the best way would be to exclude the Slf4J binding directly from the plugin. The plugin should not rely on having its own binding but rather assume that the Grails application will provide the binding (which is what it will do)

Comment: I understand that, but this just emphasizes my question even more. As it stands I don't see a way to modify the dependencies of a local plugin similar to how you would any other plugin. I eventually did exactly as you described since it's the only way I could find how, but ideally you should be able to define excludes just like any other dependency/plugin. You're right, Grails already provides a binding and so we can just make the change, but for other dependencies this may not be quite so clean cut.